# Override body attribute in HAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I am currently on a Rails project and I want to override the attributes defined in the body tag in a view that is not part of the layout.

Like this:

app/views/layouts/application.haml

```
...header

%body
  = render 'shared/menu'

  .container
    = yield
```

In another view. I want the body tag to have certain attributes:

app/views/stuff/index.haml

```
{data: {spy: 'scroll', target: '.d-sidebar', :'twttr-rendered' => 'true'}} << these attributes should apper in the body tag of the layout file. They should only be visible on the sub page
```

What is the easiest way to achieve this?

Answer (score -1):

You could probably provide it:

in layout

```
%body{ yield(:body_attributes) }
```

in view

```
- provide(:body_attributes, { class: '', data: {} })
```

Comment: Unfortunately this (the body.. yield command) raises the error 'undefined method `map' for "":ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer'